# any options other than pdf.js, for programmatically displaying PDF files in ALL browsers

Tags: pdf

I am working on a JavaScript-based application and there is a requirement to display PDF files in browsers. At the moment I am using  and  approach to embed a PDF file on the fly. This approach works in Firefox and Chrome because those browsers have built-in pdf viewer but it does not work in Internet Explorer. So I am looking for a cross-browser solution, other than pdf.js library.

Comment: can you use php? Imagick.

Comment: @Fabio I can't use PHP. It is a node.js/JavaScript/HTML5 application.

Comment: I didn't downvote... Probably because you didn't publish any code snippet you are currently working on..

Comment: PSPDFKit for Web is a cross-browser solution that even supports IE 11. It uses WebAssembly and falls back to asm.js when that is not supported. https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2017/webassembly-a-new-hope/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no alternative to Mozilla's PDF.js -- the JavaScript cross-browser solution that allows fully parse and render PDF on the client/browser side. You can try compiling some C library to asm.js/WebAssembly (PDFium or Poppler), but you will only get rasterizer of a PDF page to a bitmap. PDF.js attempts to provide more things e.g. painting via canvas API or building DOM text layer for accessibility purposes.

All other JavaScript "viewers" have to have server side, or pre-process PDF before-hand into some other format e.g. PNG (which is technically is not a PDF anymore).